# How do I verify the Snowflake Time Travel setting?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I do not see the Time Travel setting in SHOW PARAMETERS results. I have the Enterprise Edition which allows 90 day Time Travel. Does that mean it is automatically set at 90 days?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default value is 1 (even for Enterprise Edition). As you know, you can set different retention values for databases, schemas and tables. To see the value of the parameter for your account, please use the following command:

```
SHOW PARAMETERS like '%DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS%' in account;
```

Comment: Bonus is you do NOT need to be using the accountadmin role to see this. You DO need this role to change it.

Answer (score 3):

To verify time travel at schema and table level use the following commands:

SHOW PARAMETERS like '%DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS%' in table <table_name>;

SHOW PARAMETERS like '%DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS%' in schema <schema_name>;